# ClamAV no longer in the Software Center?

Tags: antivirus, clamav, clamtk

I have two questions. I found ClamTK in the Software Center. Is this just a GUI for ClamAV or is ClamAV included?

Secondly, there are many websites that say ClamAV can be downloaded from the Software Center. Example: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV

I am unable to find it in the Software Center. Does that mean that it was removed? If so, why?

Comment: Well, it's still in the repos. `sudo apt-get install clamav` works for me.

Comment: After you install `ClamTK` you will, most likely, face some **errors** when updating and running it for the first time, in such case, come back and ask on this site.

Answer (score 6):

`clamav` is still [available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=clam&searchon=names&suite=yakkety&section=all) in the repositories. Simply install it via `sudo apt-get install clamav`.

It appears that the software-center(s) [especially gnome-software] do not show all packages - I believe it actually only shows packages with graphical user interfaces.

`ClamTK` is a graphical front-end for ClamAV and pulls along the needed packages as `clamav` on installation.

If you want a full blown "old-school" graphical package manager I recommend you to go with [Synaptic](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto).

Comment: @Tony - would you mind to mark this question as solved